# error while trying to push nuget package from VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, nuget-server

I added dotnet task (.Net Core) to do a nuget push. In the Nuget server section it asked me to use create a new Nuget Connection. I went with the API Key option and game in connection name,Feed URL, and API Key.

when I run this step I get the following error

> Error: DotNetCore currently does not support using an encrypted Api
>   Key.

is this a limitation or am i doing something wrong?

Please note from my desktop I am about to create package and push the package using apikey.

Comment: Do you use private build agent? Is it your desktop machine? What's the version of dotnet core?

Comment: I have tried it on both 'Hosted VS2017' and also in the private build agent the same error. I am using .net core 2

Comment: Try to call dotnet nuget push command through Command Line task and check the result.

Comment: I have tried dotnet nuget push from command line from my desktop and it works.

Comment: Try to do it through Command Line task (Add Command Line task to build definition).

Comment: That is what I did to get it working for now. but I think that dotnet task for push is not working.

Comment: You can submit the issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues. On the other hand, you can build a custom build task through vsts extension. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushing package to NuGet server through Command Line task by calling `dotnet nuget push` command to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I faced this issue and found a alternative way for this.

Instead of using `dotnet nuget push` use `nuget push`.

[image: Azure build pipeline]

Comment: Yeap, using nuget task instead of dotnet push works as expected. Using API key as it should be.