# Publish Nuget Package using Azure Devops

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps that will publish a package to Nuget.org. The build pipeline works just fine and creates the package as the build artifact. I can publish to a feed hosted in Azure Artifacts, I just cannot publish to Nuget.org. I believe the issue is with the Service Connection. [image: Service Connection].

I've tried using the ApiKey but that throws an error

> DotNet Core does not support encrypted API Key' error

Here is the release step that is attempting to push the package.
[image]

I've also tried https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json for the Feed URL but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Log output.

> 2018-10-21T23:27:36.3177322Z ##[section]Starting: Nuget Push
>   2018-10-21T23:27:36.3183449Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-10-21T23:27:36.3183547Z Task         : .NET Core
>   2018-10-21T23:27:36.3183635Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
>   2018-10-21T23:27:36.3183729Z Version      : 2.141.0
>   2018-10-21T23:27:36.3183791Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2018-10-21T23:27:36.3183871Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
>   2018-10-21T23:27:36.3183936Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.1663123Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.1762529Z Active code page: 65001
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.1808736Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.3473599Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.4707171Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.4739974Z e3e8a3af-5c6c-44e9-820c-c62af0972256 exists true
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.4807474Z Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.4833034Z Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.4919745Z Using authentication information for the following URI: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package
>   2018-10-21T23:27:37.4988034Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\2.1.105\x64\dotnet.exe nuget push "{package}" --source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package --api-key RequiredApiKey
>   2018-10-21T23:27:38.3984300Z info : Pushing TranslatorConsole.1.0.0.6.nupkg to 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package'...
>   2018-10-21T23:27:38.4171650Z info :   PUT https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/
>   2018-10-21T23:27:38.8798808Z info :   Forbidden https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/ 462ms
>   2018-10-21T23:27:38.9562536Z error: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (The specified API key is invalid, has expired, or does not have permission to access the specified package.).
>   2018-10-21T23:27:40.2195255Z ##[error]Error: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dncs\2.1.105\x64\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
>   2018-10-21T23:27:40.2206711Z ##[error]Packages failed to publish
>   2018-10-21T23:27:40.2307763Z ##[section]Finishing: Nuget Push

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue tracked in Github: [DotNetCore currently does not support using an encrypted Api Key](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7160)

> Using an ApiKey is currently not supported in dotnet because the
>   required libraries for encrypting the key are not available, sorry for
>   the inconvenience. You should be able to use a service endpoint
>   configured with a username/password combination. If you can only use
>   an ApiKey, I would suggest using the nuget 2.* task to push.

So, you can try using the `Nuget 2.*` task to push the packages. (Add task --> Package --> Nuget)

Alternately you can try pushing package to NuGet server through Command Line task by calling `dotnet nuget push` command to deal with this issue. Reference this thread: [error while trying to push nuget package from VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374770/error-while-trying-to-push-nuget-package-from-vsts)

Comment: I switched to the Nuget task and it worked. any idea why using the username/password basic auth didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

I was dealing with the same problem - **publish a nuget to the NuGet.org feed from Azure DevOps**. Despite the fact that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52926660/4553982) is still valid, there is an easy way how to do it and the answer didn't help me much.

## Solution

### Step 1

Generate ApiKey in NuGet.org [administration](https://www.nuget.org/account/apikeys).

[image]

### Step 2

Add ApiKey as a [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) to your pipeline.

[image: Setup of secrets]

The final product should look like this:

[image: Final Secret ApiKey]

### Step 3

Update your pipeline YAML with a PowerShell task with

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'nuget push $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*.nupkg -ApiKey $(myNuGetApiKey) -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
```

You don't have to change anything in this task. It will work with any standard way of NuGet packing provided by Azure DevOps.

Publish your updated `yaml` pipeline and you are good to go.

#### Whole pipeline

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '5.7.0'
    checkLatest: true
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/YourProjectNameOr*ForAll.csproj'
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '**/YourProjectNameOr*ForAll.csproj'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'nuget push $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*.nupkg -ApiKey $(myNuGetApiKey) -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'nuget push $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*.snupkg -ApiKey $(myNuGetApiKey) -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
```

**Note:** The second task is for publishing a symbol package. If your project doesn't support the source link, you can omit this task. [This](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/improved-package-debugging-experience-with-the-nuget-org-symbol-server/) article from Karam Nandwani, the NuGet Program Manager, states that botch packages, `*.nupkg` and `*.snupkg` will by published automatically by one nuget command, but it's true. At least for now.