# Use NuGetCommand@2 to push packages to nuget.org

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

The [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) says

> To publish to an external NuGet feed, you must first create a service connection to point to that feed....

It then provides this YAML:

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections: '<Name of the NuGet service connection>'
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: push
    nuGetFeedType: external
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: <VersionVariableName>
```

This fails with

> "Error: The service connection for 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' is not valid. ApiKey service connections are not supported in this task. Instead, use -ApiKey (NuGet) or --api-key (dotnet) when invoking the tool itself. See the task documentation for more details."

I have created a service connection that points to nuget.org with my ApiKey.

I do not understand this portion of the error message: "Instead, use -ApiKey (NuGet) or --api-key (dotnet) when invoking the tool itself. See the task documentation for more details."

I have also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920786/publish-nuget-package-using-azure-devops) which refers to a deficiency which has since been implemented.

Edit:  Turns out the deficiency mentioned above is a red herring.  The real problem is a limitation of nuget which still exists as of this writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [NuGet Authenticate task document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-configure-a-nuget-package-source-that-uses-apikey-nuget-api-keys-such-as-nugetorg):

> Some package sources such as nuget.org use API keys for authentication
> when pushing packages, rather than username/password credentials. Due
> to limitations in NuGet, **this task cannot be used to set up a NuGet
> service connection that uses an API key**.
>
> Instead:
>
> 1. Configure a secret variable containing the ApiKey
> 2. Perform the package
>    push using nuget push -ApiKey $(myNuGetApiKey) or dotnet nuget push
>    --api-key $(myNuGetApiKey), assuming you named the variable myNuGetApiKey

Comment: AFAIK there is not a single Microsoft document that provides a working example of how to publish a nuget package to the largest nuget package repository on the planet, nuget.org. The only end-to-end example I know of is provided by [KUTline](/u/KUTline) and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64178172/3230660).